# Jquery scrollTop not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

My script involving scrollTop isn't working correctly in firefox.  Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slideup1").mouseover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".ftc1").delay(100).fadeIn(200);
    $(".ftc2").fadeOut(100);
    var $more = $(".footcontent").slideDown(260);
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $more.offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 260,
        queue: false
    })
});
$("#slideup2").mouseover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".ftc2").delay(100).fadeIn(200);
    $(".ftc1").fadeOut(100);
    var $more = $(".footcontent").slideDown(260);
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $more.offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 260,
        queue: false
    })
});
$("#frame").mouseover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $more = $(".footcontent").slideUp(260);
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $more.offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 260,
        queue: false
    })
});
});
```

It's not the most elegant, but generally works (except in firefox).  The scrollTop is used to keep the window at the bottom of the page as the footer slides open.  It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the footer slides open below the edge of the page, without it scrolling down with it.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6fUY5/3/

I know there's a few other posts on this subject, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code look like below. Please try and test.
For Demo in JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fUY5/5/

**Html Code**

```
<div id="frame">    
    <div class="content" style="background:#41423C">
        <div class="photogrid">
            <a href="img/1.jpg" title="day 123"><img src="img/1.jpg" width="140px" height="140px" /></a>
            <a href="img/2.jpg"><img src="img/2.jpg" width="140px" height="140px" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="footcontent">
        <div class="ftc1">
            <p>Email</p>
            <p>credit</p>
            <p>twitter</p>
            <p>facebook</p>
            <p>linkedin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ftc2">
            <p>Email2</p>
            <p>credit2</p>
            <p>twitter2</p>
            <p>facebook2</p>
            <p>linkedin2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foothead">
        <a id="slideup1" href="">Footer1</a>
        <a id="slideup2" href="">Footer2</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#frame {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        clear:both;
        position:relative;
        font-family: Gotham, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing:.3px;
        color:#eee;
        overflow:hidden;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px #222;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .content {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    .photogrid {
        height:auto;
        min-height:300px;
        width:70%;
        padding:80px 10% 80px 20%;
    }
    .photogrid img {
        width:140px;
        height:auto;
        margin:10px;
        border:2px solid #aaa;
        border-radius:4px;
    }

    footer {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#333;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
    .foothead {
        height:40px;
        width:70%;
        line-height:38px;
        color:#bbb;
        clear:both;
        padding:0 10% 0 20%;
    }
    .foothead a {
        font-size:12px;
        float:right;
        color:orange;
        padding:0 5px 0 50px;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .foothead a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .footcontent {
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        line-height:20px;
    }
    .ftc1, .ftc2 {
        display:none;
        height:auto;
        width:70%;
        padding:0 10% 0 20%;
        bottom:0px;
        position:absolute;
        clear:both;
    }
    .ftc1 p, .ftc2 p {
        font-size:12px;
        float:right;
        color:#fff;
        padding:0 5px;
    }
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Footer 1
        $('#slideup1').mouseover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".ftc1").delay(100).fadeIn(200);
            $(".ftc2").fadeOut(100);

            AnimateHover('#frame','footer');

        });

        //Footer 2
        $('#slideup2').mouseover(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".ftc2").delay(100).fadeIn(200);
            $(".ftc1").fadeOut(100);

            AnimateHover('#frame','footer');

        });

        //Ifame Hover
        $('#frame').mouseover(function(e) {
            $('.ftc1, .ftc2').fadeOut(100);
            animateLeave('#frame','footer');
        });

        //Mouse Hover
        function AnimateHover(idIframe, idFooter) {
            $(idIframe).stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-50px'
            }, 260);
            $(idFooter).stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '0'
            }, 260);
        }
        //Mouse Leave
        function animateLeave(idIframe, idFooter) {
            $(idIframe).stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '0'
            }, 260);
            $(idFooter).stop().animate({
                'margin-top': '-50px'
            }, 260);
        }

    });
```

For Demo in JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fUY5/5/